# List overlap finder

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Need to find the overlapping elements

I am doing my homework.

````
  if (a[i]==b[i]):
    print(i)```

But I got this error:
IndexError: list index out of range,


I expect result:
1 , 2 , 3 , 5 , 8 , 13
````

Comment: Try using [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: `list a` has less elements than `list b`, that's why you are getting Index error

Comment: `print(set(a).intersection(set(b)))`

Comment: if list b has 2 values for 1 i.e. `b = [1, 1, 2, 3]` would you expect your final list to be `[1, 2, 3]` or `[1, 1, 2, 3]` ?

Comment: Question was closed before I could answer, so just to add (a) it is possible to do this without sets (b) Others have correctly pointed out that the index error is because your lists are different lengths. However, the problem is much deeper than that. The fundamental mistake you made is to compare elements IN THE SAME POSITION. Intersection doesn't care about order (which is also incidently WHY sets are better than lists here).

Comment: Are you sure you understand the problem?  What is "overlap" supposed to mean?  You could interpret the task as finding matching elements, i.e., cases where the nth element of `a` has the same value as the nth element of `b`.  You could interpret the task as finding common elements, i.e, values that are found in both lists.  But if it's the latter, how come `a` has the number 1 appearing twice (aside from the fact that `a` happens to be the Fibonacci numbers).

Comment: Actually good point @PaulCornelius it's not clear whether this is even intersection. Perhaps a premature marking as duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got this error because one `list` is longer than the other. To solve this problem you can simply convert the `lists` to `sets` to eliminate duplicates, and then use the `intersection`:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

list(set(a) & set(b))
# >> [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Comment: What if there are duplicate elements in the overlap?

Comment: There cannot be, `set(a)` and `set(b)` doesn't have duplicates because they are `set`, therefore also the `intersection` will not have duplicates.

Comment: That's exactly my point. It's not clear from OP's example, but at least they show that the lists can have duplicates. So what if `a = [1,1,2], b = [1,1,3]`? I think the "overlap" should then be `[1,1]`, but yours will just yield `[1]`.

Comment: I understood what you mean, but if look at the expexted result of @555, you will see that my solution is what he need.

Comment: How do you know? None of the numbers in the expected result appear more than once in _both_ lists.

Comment: Yes, `1` appear two times in list `a`.

Comment: Yes, but 1 appears just once in `b`, so _in this example_ the correct "overlap" contains 1 just once. But what if `b` _also_ had two 1s?

Comment: Ok, I understood. In this case my solution wouldn't work. To solve you can do something with a double `for` loop or maybe use `Counter` in some way.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

print(set(a).intersection(set(b)))
# output {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13}
```

when there are more than 1 occurrence of elements in the list

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,2]

from collections import defaultdict

dic=defaultdict(int)
dic2=defaultdict(int)

for i in a:
    dic[i]+=1
for i in b:
    dic2[i]+=1

l=list(set(a) & set(b))

solution = [j for i in l for j in [i]*min(dic[i],dic2[i])]
print(solution)
# output [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
```

Comment: Or using `collections.Counter`: `[x for x, c in (Counter(a) & Counter(b)).items() for _ in range(c)]`